# HTML5 validation doesn't work in symfony twig

Tags: javascript, html, symfony

I need to take an ID number consisting 9 digits and a letter at the end. My regex looks quiet fine but the validation doesn't happen as expected.

My input tag looks like follows.

I'm using symfony twigs

```html
<input type="text" 
    id="register_idNumber" 
    placeholder="NIC Number" 
    onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" 
    pattern="^[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]$" 
    value="{{ form.idNumber.vars.value }}" 
    name="register[idNumber]" 
    required="required" 
    class="form-control" 
    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Not a valid ID number! ')"
/>
<div class="input-group-append">
```

Comment: "validation doesn't happen as expected" what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Using the inline versions of event handlers frequently allows us to lose sight of the logic necessary for proper operation.

If you are going to `.setCustomValidity()` on any error, it is set on that element forever. Your input will never be correct because you set it so.

Note in the code below, and event handler is added via code in order to support the necessary removal of the error message after a correct input occurs.

```js
const idNumber = document.querySelector('input');
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const out = document.getElementById('output');


idNumber.addEventListener('input', () => {
  out.style.display = "none";
  idNumber.setCustomValidity('');
  idNumber.checkValidity();
});

idNumber.addEventListener('invalid', () => {
  if (idNumber.value === '') {
    idNumber.setCustomValidity('Enter your id!');
  } else {
    idNumber.setCustomValidity('Must be 9 digits followed by one letter.');
  }
});

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  out.style.display = "block";
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

```css
#output{display:none}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" 
    id="register_idNumber" 
    placeholder="NIC Number" 
    onkeypress="" 
    pattern="^[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]$" 
    value="" 
    name="register[idNumber]" 
    required="required" 
    class="form-control" 
/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="output">Form submitted.</div>
```

Alternatively, refrain from using inline event handlers.

Comment: You are welcome.  Please consider [what if someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)